# How to click button element inside shadow-root with selenium - python?

Tags: python, selenium, dom, browser-automation

I am doing automation to web application and need to click on button -Login inside shadow root.

Link to html:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TcFu.jpg

Tried many different solutions - no success.

How to solve this?
Thanks in advance

Did this code:

```
###def expand_shadow_element (element):###

  global driver

  shadowRoot= driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)

return shadowRoot

### The script: ###

global driver

root = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("decoy-server-login")

shadowRoot = expand_shadow_element(root)
               shadowRoot.find_element_by_xpath("//[@id='loginForm']/p/button").click()
```

Get error:

> Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath
>   expression //*[@id='loginForm']/p/button because of the following
>   error: NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document':
>   The node provided is '#document-fragment', which is not a valid
>   context node type.

Comment: Did you try cssPath? I think i found a bug here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4971